# Add audio to video using ffmpeg not working properly in android (4.4.2) kitkat

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android

I am trying to mix an audio file to video file. The ffmpeg command I am using for that is written below:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i audio.mp3 -map 0:a:0 -map 1:v:0 -codec copy -shortest output_video.avi
```

It's working fine on the Android phones version below 4.4, but when I am trying to run the same command for Android kitkat(4.4.2), it's giving me the exit code 0 but the output is not able to play itself on default android player, it's giving the message that can't able to play the video, but if i am trying to play the same output in external media player like VLC (for android) then it's able to play the output video. The logcat result is written below:

> `ffmpeg version git-2013-12-11-3b28564 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers  built on Jan 22 2014 13:22:00 with gcc 4.6 (GCC) 20120106 (peelease)  configuration: --arch=arm --target-os=linux --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --prefix=../build --sysroot=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm --extra-cflags=' -I/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I../libmp3lame/include -I../libx264/include -DANDROID -marm -march=armv6 ' --extra-ldflags=' -L/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -L../libmp3lame/lib -L../libx264/lib' --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avfilter --enable-decoders --enable-demuxers --enable-encoders --enable-filters --enable-indevs --enable-network --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-swscale --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100  libavcodec     55. 48.102 / 55. 48.102  libavformat    55. 25.101 / 55. 25.101  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102  libavfilter     4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104  libpostproc 52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100[mp3 @ 0x18ea210] Header missingInput #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/trimmedaudio.mp3':  Metadata:    publisher       : Ninja Tune       encoder         : Lavf55.25.101  Duration: 00:00:54.99, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 227 kb/s    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s    Stream #0:1:`
>
> `Video: png, rgb24, 512x512, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc    Metadata:      title           : thumbnail      comment         : Cover (front)Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/input0.mp4':  Metadata:    major_brand     : mp42    minor_version   : 0    compatible_brands: isommp42    creation_time   : 2013-04-08 10:00:41  Duration: 00:00:55.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 545 kb/s    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360, 446 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)    Metadata:      handler_name    : VideoHandler    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)`
>
> `Metadata:      creation_time   : 2013-04-08 10:00:42     5-11-2011Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Videowthnwaudio.mp4':  Metadata:    publisher   encoder         : Lavf55.25.101    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x360, q=2-31, 446 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)    Metadata:      handler_name    : VideoHandler    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/sStream mapping:  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)Press [q] to stop, [?] for helpframe= 1669 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4364kB time=00:00:55.65 bitrate= 642.4kbits/s    video:3034kB audio:1290kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.924174%`

Comment: Well, I've never used ffmpeg before, though I could suggest you [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) for this. It's like a swiss knife for video files. You can download the portable version, drag your video to the program window, click on the `MP3 22KHz 63 KBps Stereo` (Example) on the title of the video and add your audio to it. It lets you save into various formats and the gui is should be much better than the ffmpeg.

Comment: @mk117 appreciate your answer. but I want to use ffmpeg only. Anyway I found a way to do it. thanks for your help... :)

Comment: You're welcome! I guess you wanted batch processing in command line of the video files , and that's why you and many people here on this site use ffmpeg.